# Clarification on notes about measures on polish spaces

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reading these notes [http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vangaans/jancol1.pdf](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Evangaans/jancol1.pdf)
In theorem 2.6 (page 5), it is proved that for $(X,d)$ being a complete separable metric space, every finite Borel measure on $X$ is tight. Then on page 14, there is the remark that in theorem 2.6. it is proved that if $(X,d)$ is a complete separable metric space, then {$\mu$} is tight for each ${\cal{P}}(X)$.

This is what I can't understand. In  the Theorem 2.6. it's dealing with a single measure, whereas he makes the remark abot a sequence of measures. How is this bridged?

Note that, I haven't included more text and have referred to the link since the notes are pretty famous and it would take me pages to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tightness really refers to two things which are very closely related. Specifically, a *measure* $\mu$ on $X$ is tight if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\mu(X\setminus K)<\varepsilon$. A *set of measures* $\mathcal A\subset\mathcal P(X)$ is tight if, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\mu(X\setminus K)<\varepsilon$ for *all* $\mu\in\mathcal A$.

With these definitions in mind, the measure $\mu$ is tight if and only if the singleton set $\{\mu\}$ is tight. In particular, if $X$ is a complete and separable metric space, the singleton set $\{\mu\}$ is tight for every finite measure $\mu$ on $X$.

Comment: Just so that I understand correctly: In the remark in the notes, the author by {$\mu$} means the singleton set and not a sequence of measures?    Also, does the fact that a measure $\mu$ on $X$ is tight, imply or help to prove that a collection of probability measures {$\mu_1,...,\mu_n$} on $X$ is tight?

Comment: Yes, the author means the singleton set. And yes, if $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n$ are each tight measures, then the set $\{\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n\}$ is also tight. The proof is not difficult (it relies mostly on the fact that a finite union of compact sets is compact), and is a good exercise I encourage you to try.